# Google App Engine Application-Owned Drive API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm setting up an application-owned service which can access it's own Drive (and I will share private spreadsheets with it).

According to the [Developer Page for Account Services #AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts#google_app_engine_project_service_accounts#google_app_engine_project_service_accounts):

- "In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Drive API." (DONE)
- "To find your application's API key, expand the Browser Key or Server Key sections" (Can't seem to find that, but I was prompted to download a key with "notasecret" - not sure if this is it and where the key is).
- Next, it gives start examples, but not in PHP. Do I have to download and include the [Google API for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)?

Comment: or do I use "[app identity](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/appidentity/#PHP_Asserting_identity_to_Google_APIs)." this is so confusing... so many APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"To find your application's API key, expand the Browser Key or Server Key sections" (Can't seem to find that, but I was prompted to download a key with "notasecret" - not sure if this is it and where the key is).**

Go to this URL

```
https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:999999999999:access
```

where 99999999 is the numeric project ID which you can find at the top of the screen, or embedded within your URL. ^f for API Key, or scroll down around 3/4 of the page.

**Next, it gives start examples, but not in PHP. Do I have to download and include the Google API for PHP?**
You can either access it using the raw http rest API, or use the PHP wrapper library. Examples of both canbe found in the respective API reference pages, eg https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list